# Overheating, water reservoir bubbling

Tags: chevrolet, overheating, malibu

2001 Chevy Malibu - Squeeze both radiator hoses they are soft like not getting water maybe water pump. Like the water isn't getting to the motor maybe the water pump stuck. The radiator overflow is boiling and then it empties out but it gets too hot and it just shut off.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out the radiator cap if, as you say, the hoses stay soft.

The fluid needs to be under pressure as this increases the boiling point so the system can work as designed.

This is also why opening the rad cap on a hot engine is so dangerous...